# While loop does not get updated global variable in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, infinite-loop

**I am trying to save data to an array every 5 seconds.** First, I tried this:

```
setInterval(function() { 
    data.push({
        price: getCurrentPrice(),
        time: moment().format()
    })
}, 5000);
```

After running for exactly 30 minutes, the setInterval method slips by 1 second, this is intolerable for my use case, so I tried something different using moment.js library:

```
while(true){
    if(moment().diff(lastSaveTime, 'seconds')==5){
        lastSaveTime = moment();
        data.push({
            price: getCurrentPrice(),
            time: lastSaveTime.format()
        })
    }
}
```

In an infinite while loop, data is saved if the last data save time is 5 seconds earlier. This works perfectly, however, there is an issue:

**While loop doesnt get the updated value that getCurrentPrice() is supposed to return. It returns the same value in the infinite while loop. Is there any way around this?**

Comment: are you trying to do this in NodeJS or browser

Comment: It is in the nodejs server

Comment: problem with infinite loops is that no asynchronous functions get a chance to run, though the code you presented only you know if that's going to be a problem

Comment: instead of setInterval, think of how you could use setTimeout with a timeout value calculated such that there is no cumulative drift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a very good idea to write such an infinite loop, as this blocks the event loop, and nothing else will be allowed to run.

I would recommend using something like this https://gist.github.com/tanepiper/4215634

Since its mentioned it is for NodeJs you could use some npm modules that already accounts for the inaccuracy of timer. for example https://github.com/aduth/correctingInterval or  https://github.com/klyngbaek/accurate-interval

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need